# UIImageView is not changing orientation when added as subview to window

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a background image in UIViewController and RootViewController. I have added both viewController's View inside window as follows

```
        MainMenuBavkGround_ipad *backImage = [[MainMenuBavkGround_ipad alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuBavkGround_ipad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    RootViewController *rootviewController = (RootViewController *)[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    backImage.m_rootViewController = rootviewController;
    rootviewController._buttons = Buttons;
    rootviewController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(250.0, 200.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    rootviewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window addSubview:backImage.view];
```

But now UIViewController (MainMenuBavkGround_ipad) is not changing its orientation. even it does not calls shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

If i reverse order of adding views in window then RootViewController's view is not changing orientation.

and if i add UIViewControoler's view on window and add RootViewController's view on UIViewController's view then **viewDidAppear** of rootViewController does not invoke.

I tried calling shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation manually. but it does not worked.

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: It seems i can not handle that see the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved Problem!!!!!!

By [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html) I got that i can not add two viewcontroller's views in window. So what I tried is i searched for how to set tableview background; and i got a [post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1746-how-set-uitableview-background-image.html) by user ama269 and then I set my window background color to the image by following code.

```
 window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scrn_01_iPad.png"]];
```

and whenever my view get orientation notification i do following to change the differnet orientation image.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {;
if( (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad))
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    {
        self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1st_scrn_iPad_L.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
        self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scrn_01_iPad.png"]];

    }
}
```

}

And then my problem is solved now  **viewDidAppear** of rootViewController get invoke. and my image orientations also get handled.

Thanks to ama269